# How can I see which of my edits on Wikipedia have been reverted?

Tags: wikipedia

I'd like to see a list of all of my Wikipedia edits which have been subsequently reverted (as opposed to the ones that have been retained). How is it possible to do this?

Comment: It's hard to do this, because it's hard to define what exactly “reverted” means. What if you added a section, then other people made edits to this section and then somebody else removed the section. Should that count as a revert? How could you detect something like that?

Comment: All reverted edit summaries on Wikipedia contain the text (in italics) that reads "Reverted edits by (name of user) to last version by (name of previous editor)". This is how reverts can be distinguished from other edits.

Comment: Important and interesting question, despite difficulty.  If it were convenient to detect when one's edits were unmade, there would probably be more conflicts on wikimedia.  On the other hand, and more importantly, it maybe contribute to the reform of an epidemic of [naysaying](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Pi&diff=632843944&oldid=632830558) in crowdsourced media.

Comment: @BobStein I just don't get it -- how is deleting 1000 digits of pi naysaying? Sorry I'm dense here...

Comment: @JosiahYoder hmm, which is the issue (1) how deleting content is naysaying, or (2) whether 1000 digits of pi belong on Wikipedia? I meant naysaying in the sense of a user saying "nay" to content by deleting it. I think 1000 digits of pi is useful if only [visually](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Pi&oldid=632830558#Pi_to_1000_digits). Not sure how much it's changed in ten years, but I had noticed some overdone deletion on Wikipedia and Stack Overflow.

Comment: @BobStein Thank you. I was asking (1) and you answered clearly.

Answer (score 4):

[Wikipedia's notification system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Notifications) notifies its users about reverted edits, so it's very easy to find them now -- simply click on the "Bell" icon in the top right corner of the page. Any reverts to edits you have made will show up in this list.

Historically, monitoring the watchlist was your only option. You can still use your browser's *find* option to highlight what you are looking for.

But even the new feature doesn't guarantee that you will find everything that you want -- maybe your edits get removed without “revert” or “undo” tools.

Comment: This answer is now outdated. [Wikipedia's notification system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Notifications) notifies its users about reverted edits, so it's very easy to find them now.